# Merge multiple xlsx files into a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have multiple xlsx data files with different number of rows. How can I merge them into a data frame? My code

```r
library(readxl)

fnames <- list.files()

xlxs <- lapply(fnames, read_xlsx)

a<-data.frame(xlxs)
```

But the last line does not work since number of rows are not same for all files.

Comment: `df <- purrr::map_dfr(list.files(), readxl::read_excel)`

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
a <- bind_rows(xlxs)
```

Also, it is better to specify the `pattern`

```
fnames <- list.files(pattern = "\\.xlsx", full.names = TRUE)
```

Comment: I often also like to have the input filenames referenced in the final data frame. You can use `xlsx <- setNames(xlsx, fnames)`, then add .id = "input_filename" to the bind_rows call to get it easily.

Answer (score 0):

The `purrr` option from @alistaire are likely better options, but in case anyone needs/wants to do this in `base`, you can do:

```
a <- do.call(rbind, xlsx)
```